# MongoDB: How to query for records where field is null or not set?

Tags: mongodb, null, mongodb-query, exists

I have an `Email` document which has a `sent_at` date field:

```
{
  'sent_at': Date( 1336776254000 )
}
```

If this `Email` has not been sent, the `sent_at` field is either null, or non-existant.

I need to get the count of all sent/unsent `Emails`. I'm stuck at trying to figure out the right way to query for this information. I think this is the right way to get the sent count:

```
db.emails.count({sent_at: {$ne: null}})
```

But how should I get the count of the ones that aren't sent?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

If the `sent_at` field is not there when its not set then:

```javascript
db.emails.count({sent_at: {$exists: false}})
```

If it's there and null, or not there at all:

```javascript
db.emails.count({sent_at: null})
```

If it's there and null:

```javascript
db.emails.count({sent_at: { $type: 10 }})
```

---

The [Query for Null or Missing Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/) section of the MongoDB manual describes how to query for null and missing values.

> ### Equality Filter
>
> The `{ item : null }` query matches documents that either contain the item field whose value is `null` *or* that do not contain the `item` field.
>
> ```javascript
> db.inventory.find( { item: null } )
> ```

> ### Existence Check
>
> The following example queries for documents that do not contain a field.
>
> The `{ item : { $exists: false } }` query matches documents that do not contain the `item` field:
>
> ```javascript
> db.inventory.find( { item : { $exists: false } } )
> ```

> ### Type Check
>
> The `{ item : { $type: 10 } }` query matches *only* documents that contain the `item` field whose value is `null`; i.e. the value of the item field is of [BSON Type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) `Null` (type number `10`) :
>
> ```javascript
> db.inventory.find( { item : { $type: 10 } } )
> ```

Comment: Now that's a complete answer. Simply brilliant! Thanks

Answer (score 22):

If you want to ONLY count the documents with `sent_at` defined with a value of `null` (don't count the documents with `sent_at` not set):

```
db.emails.count({sent_at: { $type: 10 }})
```

Comment: Thank you. When checking if field exists but set to null this is very useful.

Comment: Upvoted because when using `find` with plain `null` it interprets values like  `0.0` as `null` and this solution avoids this

Answer (score 18):

Use:

```
db.emails.count({sent_at: null})
```

Which counts all emails whose sent_at property is null or is not set.
The above query is same as below.

```
db.emails.count({$or: [
  {sent_at: {$exists: false}},
  {sent_at: null}
]})
```

Answer (score 10):

Seems you can just do single line:

```
{ "sent_at": null }
```

Answer (score 4):

All the above answers are amazing and correct. Just want to add one improvement on the answers which is using `$type`.

[Starting with MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types), you can avoid using `10` (as hardcoded literals reduce the code readability) and instead can simply use string aliases i.e. `"null"`. So to summarize-

#### 1. If you want to pick records where `sent_at` exists and has the value `null`

```js
db.emails.count({sent_at: { $type: 'null' }});

// or
// This reduces the code readability as your peer might not know
// that what is the meaning of value 10
db.emails.count({sent_at: { $type: 10 }});
```

#### 2. If you want to pick records which has either `sent_at: null` or `sent_at` does not exist

```js
// This will ensure both the conditions
db.emails.count({ sent_at: null })
```

#### 3. If you only want records where `sent_at` does not exist

```js
db.emails.count({sent_at: { $exists: false }});
```

#### 4. If you only want to pick `sent_at` where the field exists and may have any value

```js
db.emails.count({sent_at: { $exists: true }});
```

Remember, this will pull any document of `emails` which has any value including `null`, `0`, `''`, `false`.

Answer (score 3):

If it is required t check existence of attribute and value equals null in the same document as-

```
db.emails.count($or: [
  {sent_at: {$exists: false}},
  {sent_at: null}
])
```

Above can be done in a single line-query which will take lesser time as-

```
db.emails.count($or: [ {sent_at: nil }])
```

because `nil` will fetch documents if the key `doesn't exist` too in addition to value is `null`.
[Better to have a glance on source](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-if-a-field-exist-or-is-null-from-golang/105943) it has saved my day.

> Note: Use `nil` instead of `null` in newer version of mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

you can use $in operator to check both cases

```
db.emails.find({"sent_at": {$in:[null,""]}).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
db.emails.find($and:[{sent_at:{$exists:true},'sent_at':null}]).count()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.employe.find({ $and:[ {"dept":{ $exists:false }, "empno": { $in:[101,102] } } ] }).count();
```