# excluding from $match if data is blank or null in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am getting trouble in `$match` in `mongodb`.

Lets say I have multiple `$match` options in some case some options are `blank` or `null` at that stage I want to `$match` do match that field in our document.

For Example

```
$match:{
   name:'abc',
   age:''  //exclude if blank or null,
   city:'delhi'
}
```

I want it only match `name` and `city` field.  I want it exclude auto if `blank` or `null` possible from aggregation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to query for records where field is null or not set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591543/mongodb-how-to-query-for-records-where-field-is-null-or-not-set)

Comment: You mean you don't want the 'age' "fieldname" in the results if is is blank or null, but to be there where it is not, don't you? i.e `{ "name": "abc", "city": "delhi" },{ "name": "def":, "age": 25, "city": "sydney" }`

Answer (score 10):

As your question heading **excluding from $match if data is blank or null in mongodb** suggests that you want to exclude if data is blank and null. You should use `$and` to match condition like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$match:{"name":"abc","city":"delhi","$and":[{"age":{"$ne":""}},{"age":{"$ne":null}}]}} )
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you documents look like this:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87313fc92af6b6b2f9497"), "name" : "abc", "age" : "", "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87314fc92af6b6b2f9498"), "name" : "abc", "age" : "", "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87314fc92af6b6b2f9499"), "name" : "abc", "age" : "", "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87319fc92af6b6b2f949a"), "name" : "abc", "age" : 2, "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c8731cfc92af6b6b2f949b"), "name" : "abc", "age" : 3, "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87320fc92af6b6b2f949c"), "name" : "abc", "age" : 4, "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87324fc92af6b6b2f949d"), "name" : "abc", "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87325fc92af6b6b2f949e"), "name" : "abc", "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87326fc92af6b6b2f949f"), "name" : "abc", "city" : "delhi" }
```

Here I suppose `age` type is **Double**.

You need to use the [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) and the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operators. The first one to filter the documents where `age` is present and the latter where its value is not blank.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "abc", "age": { "$exists": true, "$type": 1 }}}
])
```

The shorter way to write the above is:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "abc", "age": { "$type": 1 }, "city": "delhi" }}
])
```

because the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator matches only if the field **exists** and  is of the [*specified type*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types).

---

If `$match` is the only pipeline operator in your *aggregation* then you don't need *aggregation*. Simply use the [**`.find`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method.

```js
db.collection.find({'name': 'abc', age: {$type: 1}, city: 'delhi' })
```

Output:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87319fc92af6b6b2f949a"), "name" : "abc", "age" : 2, "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c8731cfc92af6b6b2f949b"), "name" : "abc", "age" : 3, "city" : "delhi" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c87320fc92af6b6b2f949c"), "name" : "abc", "age" : 4, "city" : "delhi" }
```